# Get the other key with the value of in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array, how to get the minimum value of a key and get the other keys related to that array such as:-

```
Case 1:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [sum] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
            [sum] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 3
            [sum] => 9
        )

)
```

I want to get the minimum sum i.e 5 and number(1) in this case. If there are multiple keys with same minimum value such as :-

```
Case 2:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [sum] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
            [sum] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 3
            [sum] => 9
        )

)
```

In this case 2 i want to get 'number' as `rand(1,2)`

Where `$arrayn = the above multidimensional array`

```
$min_no = min(array_column($arrayn, 'sum'));
$min_count = array_filter($arrayn, function ($get_number) {
  global $min_no;
  return ($get_number['sum'] == $min_no);
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayn);
echo '</pre>';
$winning_number =$min_count[array_rand($min_count)]['number'];
```

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: I need an alternate solution to achive my test cases

Comment: @user11566267 How would you judge it's correctness? You are using rand() here, so you can't do a 1 to 1 mapping for the test cases.

Comment: What do you mean by achieve your test cases? Your current solution doesn't pass all your test cases? If that's the case you should provide which test case your current solution doesn't pass, so that people can understand your issue in order to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a simple `foreach`, avoiding the use of any of PHPs `array_*` functions:

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$output = array();
foreach ($arrayn as $array) {
    if ($array['sum'] < $min) {
        $output = array($array);
        $min = $array['sum'];
    }
    elseif ($array['sum'] == $min) {
        $output[] = $array;
    }
}
$winning_number = rand(0, count($output)-1);
print_r($output[$winning_number]);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PW0s3)